# Unexpected results while tallying rng totals

Tags: c++

I've made a trivial program to simulate rolling a 4 sided dice and count how many times each number comes up so that I can see how random rand() is. When I simply print the results the only digits that come up are numbers 1->4 as intended. When I do a tally I noted that of 1000 iterations I only ended up with ~700 ticks between 1 and 4. Why would this be? I feel like the answer should be obvious because the loop functions as intended but I can't see where the problem arises when I look at the suspected problem area of my code.

```
int d4()
{
    int x;
    x = rand() % 4 + 1;
    return x;
}  


int main()
{
    int n1 = 0;
    int n2 = 0;
    int n3 = 0;
    int n4 = 0;
    int n5 = 0;
    srand(time(0));
    int x = 0;
    while (x <= 100)
    {

        std::cout << d4() << " ";
        ++x;

/*      ++x;
        if (d4() == 1)
            ++n1;
        else if (d4() == 2)
            ++n2;
        else if (d4() == 3)
            ++n3;
        else if (d4() == 4)
            ++n4;
        else
            ++n5;           */
    }

    std::cout << "Number 1 was rolled " << n1 << " times." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Number 2 was rolled " << n2 << " times." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Number 3 was rolled " << n3 << " times." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Number 4 was rolled " << n4 << " times." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Somehow some other number was rolled on a 4 sided die " << n5 << " times.";

    std::cin.ignore();
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Note: I've commented out the tally snippet to manually look at the results.

Comment: In your long `if ... else if` cascade, you are calling `d4()` multiple times. It returns a different random value each time. That's how you fall through to `n5`. Call it once per iteration of the loop, store the value in a variable.

Comment: You probably want to store the result in a variable and then compare its value.  Think about what happens when you say `if (d4() == 1)` and it isn't.  What happens every time you call `d4()`?  New random number.

Comment: Better way  to do d4: `std::default_random_engine engine;  std::uniform_int_distribution<int> uniform(1,4); auto d4 = std::bind (uniform, engine);` Then just `val = d4();` Documentation: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out in the comments, your problem is that each time you call `d4()` it returns a different result between `1` and `4` (inclusive). What this can mean is in your loop, the return of `d4()` never ends up equalling the compared value at the time of the comparison. Consider:

```
    if (d4() == 1) // call d4(), which returns 2
        ++n1;
    else if (d4() == 2) // call d4() again, which returns 3
        ++n2;
    else if (d4() == 3) // call d4() again, which returns 1
        ++n3;
    else if (d4() == 4) // call d4() again, which returns 2
        ++n4;
    else
        ++n5; // No other comparison worked, so this is incremented instead.
```

The solution here is to **only call `d4()` once** and save its value in a variable.

```
// Retrieve the random number this loop iteration and store its value
int randomNumber = d4();
std::cout << randomNumber << std::endl;

if (randomNumber == 1)
    ++n1;
else if (randomNumber  == 2)
    ++n2;
else if (randomNumber  == 3)
    ++n3;
else if (randomNumber  == 4)
    ++n4;
else
    ++n5;
```

Comment: Plus `rand() % 4` does _not_ have an even distribution. OP needs to do some basic background reading on PRNGs and modulo arithmetic.

Comment: Lightning, the idea was to make a trivial program to see how even rand() is. OP is aware loosely aware of rand()'s flaws. I am making this program not because I'm not clever enough to read but because it was an example of something I can code to help me learn C++.